# customization for frame

Tags: iphone

Usually, before setting up a UILabel, we have to initialize CGRect like below

> ```
> CGRect  frame       =   CGRectMake(277, 357, 10, 15);
> UILabel *myLabel    =   [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
> ```

If I dont use CGRect frame, are there any CGGeometry such as following **CGEclipse**

```
**CGEllipse**  frame       =   CGRectMake(277, 357, 10, 15);
UILabel *myLabel    =   [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Please give me some hints about this issue. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe that 'eclipse' was the word you were looking for, more likely you meant 'ellipse', I fixed that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not that simple. CGRect is a struct, and it does not support inheritance (e.g. `CGEllipse`, `CGTriangle`, etc.)

However, you can do the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stack-overflow.jpg"];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, imageView.bounds);

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] initWithLayer:imageView.layer];
    shapeLayer.path = path;
    [imageView.layer setMask:shapeLayer];
}
```

If you include `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to your project and link against `QuartzCore.framework`.

For more information about `CGMutablePathRef`, check [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html)